# Limit the field that are syncronized

Tags: sql, windows-mobile, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I'm building an application that runs on a Windows Mobile device. I'm using Microsoft's Sync Framework to sync the Sql CE database with the main corporate db.

The question is how can I limit the fields that are syncronized? The table in question has stacks of fields but I only need to display a few of them on the mobile device and replication is only one way (from the server to the mobile) so that shouldn't be an issue. I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837683/can-you-select-which-column-to-sync-with-sync-framework) similar question but there's not much info there. Can anyone give me more advice on how to achieve this? I imagine that it's a very common requirement.

Also, does anyone know if I can use the Sync Framework Version 2.0 or do I have to stick to 1.0. I had a feeling that 2.0 doesn't support Windows Mobile but I'm not sure.

Cheers
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the T-SQL that's generated behind the scenes to not include all the columns of the table, but there are a couple of gotchas here. Firstly, it means that you can't use a wizard to modify the sync selection later - not a big deal, and creating your own partial class to override just the specific method with the T-SQL for your table mitigates that a bit.

Second, changes to the unincluded (not sure if that's a word?) columns can also trigger a download of that row as by default the change tracking is by row. You can change this by setting the Track_Columns_Updated flag

```
ALTER TABLE Employee
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING
WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON)
```

Depending on the number of rows and size of the data and frequency updated, I have often found an easier solution is to provide a trigger on the main table of the server to update records in a separate table containing just the data you need, then sync that. It makes it much easier to change what's downloaded later. This is obviously not a solution if you are downloading the entire works of Shakespeare, but for a few 1000 records of a product catalogue, I think it's perfectly feasible.

Comment: Looks like some sensible suggestions. Thanks a lot Johny! I'll check it out in the next few days and update this question. I'm really struggling with the sync framework.

Comment: I'm sick of struggling with the sync framework. My requirements are pretty simple, one-way sync so I think some custom code will be vastly simpler and faster running.

Cheers

Mark